# How to hide setup part for any profile?

Tags: administration

i want to hide setup functionality for any user how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to Manage Users -> Profiles and for each profile you want change, go to System Permissions and uncheck the very last one on the page:  View the App Setup and Administrative Settings pages.
Please choose this as the best answer if this resolves your query.

Thanks,
Vipul